# Accessing shared styles from an Angular2 NgModule

Tags: angular, module, sass, reusability, angular-cli

I have an Angular2 project (generated by `angular-cli`). In the project I have a main module and a sub-module. The sub-module represents a well defined concept, so it fits well to have it as (potentially reusable) `NgModule`.

The sub-module encapsulates the different components, and only exposes one component outwards. That is all nice, it works well so the module could be reusable.

However, the module does have one global dependency, that stops it from being fully decoupled, reusable module. A `scss` file accesses a common `scss` file using `@import`. The common `scss` file is outside the module.

So, specifically, a `scss` style file inside the module refers to a `scss` file outside the module using relative paths, like this:

```sass
@import './../../../assets/styles/common-props';
```

I don't want to copy the `scss` file into the module. What is the best way to consume the common `scss` file, so that the module becomes easy to reuse? Is there a best practice?

Comment: can you post some of the code.  I'd like to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JohnBaird added code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is really a best practice here.  It all depends on how you want to import and manage external SCSS resources.

1. If you want the SCSS resource to be updated by a Homebrew or NPM update then importing it from its source directory is the way to go.
2. If you want to manually control the upgrade path to the SCSS resource then simply move the file into your SCSS hierarchy and import.

Generally, I prefer approach #2.

I have a directory called 'libs' that I organize external SCSS / CSS files into and simply import out of that folder structure.

There are edge cases where I use #1, but they are rare.

Comment: In scenario 2, won't you have to hard code a relative path to the SCSS file into the module, making it non-reusable for other projects?

Comment: In scenario 1, are you saying that I can make a node module out of a scss file and publish it to our internal npm server?

Comment: I am not sure I am answering your question, maybe I don't understand it fully.  Maybe include your entire SCSS structure and show how you want those external SCSS resources incluced into your master import file?